# Scheme : Parsing a string

Tags: string, list, scheme

I want to convert a string `"(1 2 3 4)"` to a list `(1 2 3 4)`.
How can this be done using Scheme?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the built-in `read` function by turning the string into an "input port" (an abstraction of a file opened for reading):

```
(read (open-input-string "(1 2 3 4)")) ;; evaluates to (1 2 3 4)
```

That works in both Guile and Racket. Depending on your Scheme implementation, you might also need to import the [SRFI-6](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-6/srfi-6.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Guide in Racket:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/read-write.html?q=read